# MsGraphApi : Response Error while creating graph subscription

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I'm Building my java Spring boot Application to be able to intercept subscription validation token and returning it to create a graph subscription.

the problem is that it was working.

```
@RequestMapping("graph")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getToken(
        @RequestParam(required = false , name = "validationToken") String validationToken
    ){
        if(validationToken != null){
            System.out.println("|" + validationToken.substring(81) + "|");
            validationToken = validationToken.substring(81);
        }
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(validationToken, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }    
}
```

The code is easy and clear, it responds with an object that holds the 200 code and the actual test, which is demanded by [Graph Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http#create-a-subscription)

But now I get this Error:

> Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter

Here's the curl i send

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer [Token]' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "https://c806-81-192-174-99.ngrok-free.app/graph/webhook",
    "resource": "/me/mailfolders('\''inbox'\'')/messages",
    "expirationDateTime": "2023-05-09T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "SecretClient"
}'
```

I also use Ngrok to expose my local, which was working just fine, it shows the response code as 200 in every request and i see the body in the terminal which seems perfectly fine.

In the debug mode, before sending the request here's the object i send :

> 

```
body:"8954e8f7-6cbd-47cf-bf51-c2ce94f7c32f"
headers:ReadOnlyHttpHeaders@77 [header object]
status:
    name:"OK"
    ordinal:4
    reasonPhrase:"OK"
    series:
        name:"SUCCESSFUL"
        ordinal:1
        value:2
    value:200
```